# ASCII- Error Message, Cannot Find symbol

Tags: java, string, ascii

private void btnTranslateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String strSecretMessage;

```
    strSecretMessage = this.txtSecretMessage.getText();

    for (int i=0; i < (strSecretMessage.length()-1); i++){
        lblACSII.setText(i+" "+ strSecretMessage.charCodeAt(i));
    }
}
```

Error for charCodeAt pops up, says cannot find symbol.

Comment: Are you meaning to use the method `charAt()`?

Comment: Thats not an actual method: `charAt`?

Comment: I'm trying to convert to ASCII. I need to display the corresponding ASCII character to the letter.

Comment: @alexphan As we have suggested, did you try using `charAt()`? `charCodeAt()` is not a method declared in `String`.

Comment: I have tried that, it only displays the character at the certain digit of the string.

Comment: I need to display the ASCII number with the assigned digit of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lblACSII.setText(i+" "+ (int)strSecretMessage.charAt(i));
```

`charAt()` get the char and casting it to `int` will provide the ascii value

```
String temp = "";
for (int i=0; i < (strSecretMessage.length()-1); i++){
     temp += i+" "+ strSecretMessage.charCodeAt(i) + " ";
 }
lblACSII.setText(temp);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I also need a little more help, when I run and type a string the conversion only shows the first letter's corresponding ASCII code. Example: CAT  Output: 1   65

Comment: suppose string is `ABCD` do you want to print `65 66 67 68` ?

Comment: @alexphan `setText()` will replace the existing text each time. Consider concatenating all of the values beforehand, then setting the text equal to that `String`.

Comment: Yes that is the output i'm looking for

Comment: New to coding, how do you concatenate all of the values and then set the text?

Comment: declare a temp variable outside the loop, concatenate the value in loop to this temp variable. And then do `setText()` outside the loop

Comment: @alexphan Did you initialize it to an empty `String`?